# How to create a particle with animation on birth and death of particles

Tags: animation, particles, animation-nodes

I want to create an emitter that emits particles that they have animation on birth, and they die when animation ends, or their life ends after their death animation or smth like that!

Is there a way to make such thing, any way rather than animation node which I started to work recently?

Comment: animation nodes work in all versions. I don't know where you got your wrong info from. And if it doesn't work for you, i would suggest asking on github and open an issue for that. I got it installed even on 4.2 alpha....

Comment: so i would suggest you improve your question instead of writing wrong facts.

Comment: ..or to put it more gently.. perhaps tell us what leads you to the conclusion AN is not working in recent versions, since at least one person can't reproduce the failure :)

Comment: I installed 4.0 clean, attempted to install AN, and blender prompted that uses old python version, so I gave up, but you answer light it up that works, so I change the qustion and follow the AN as well.
Thanks Chris

Comment: you can download animation nodes here: https://animation-nodes.com/#download of course - you have to choose the right version for your case (python version/computer etc). If this still doesn't work, you can compile AN yourself which is explained in the animation github infos.

Comment: also keep in mind, Blender python version is another (!) python version than you have on your computer. Blender has its own python version "inside". So just typing python -v won't help.

Answer (score 1):

ok, here a very (!) simple example (unfortunately you didn't specify in any way how your animation should look like):

[image]

first i got all dead particles data via "particles data" node. Thankfully AN provides the locations for that. Then i save the die date (frame) for each object in custom attributes (frame start) in the subprogram "set die date".
Finally in subprogram "calc new loc" i calculate the new locations for the instanced particles (object instancer) via a very primitive formula: just adding some z-values to the die-locations.

The result:

The particles "lift up" after dying.

[image]

---

Update:

i just found out, that particles info has (!) already the die dates...so here is a much simpler way:

[image]